Chess problem content in Ludwig TV Show?
My UK-based brother informs me that a recent popular TV series called Ludwig contains some chess. According to one review there is a scene of "reverse chess (where maths, probability and reason are used to determine prior moves in the middle of a chess game)" i.e. retrograde analysis?
Has anyone in the UK seen the show and can share the chess problem content, please, as it's hard to access legally from overseas?

They went that-a-way? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3DqxrZ6Ntg

As I remember it it was along the lines of "given this position find the game that must have occurred" whatever that is called but I would have to re-view to be sure. I also remember not being that impressed with the chess content, though I enjoyed the series as a whole.

@HaukeReddmann yes that's it - thanks for locating it. Saves me a lot of time. That is even more cringe-inducing than the chess in the relevant Columbo & Agatha Christie episodes! Well that's dramedy for you
